# import customers - link with one time login and password change

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

we plan to import 4000 customers from our ERP into Magento CE.

We thought about emails to customers with a one time login link and the following request to set their own password.
An alternative would be to create random password and to import them. But we don't want to send 4000 letters with the login data. Via email would be not secure enough.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or has anyone another idea to import 4000 customers without existing passwords?

Comment: why dont you simple import same password for every customer ?

Comment: And can I force customers to change their passwords on first login?

Comment: you can but for this you need to add some custom code using observers, so that customers cannot proceed to any page except change password till they change it.. hope this makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how magento sends the password reset mail in `Mage_Customer_AccountController::forgotPasswordPostAction`.
Since Magento 1.6 it is supported to send a password reset link instead of the password itself. When creating your customer you could use `$customer->generatePassword();`  to generate a random password and set it with `$customer->setNewPassword($password);`. After the customer was stored, the reminder email can be sent:

```
$newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
```

To use an own emailtemplate, have a look at `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail`.